# Virtual robot controller?

Tags: ros, simulation, motoman, ros-industrial, motoman-driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm working with a physical robot with a physical controller, but I can not always be in front of it.
Is there a way to connect me to a virtual controller(in my case, FS100) to test my programs?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193656/virtual-robot-controller?/) by [Bastbeat](https://answers.ros.org/users/12796/bastbeat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2014-09-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is there a way to connect me to a virtual controller(in my case, FS100) to test my programs?

I'm assuming you mean *ROS application* when you say *programs* in your question, not MotoPlus applications.

---

Motoman has [MotoSim](http://www.motoman.co.uk/en/products/software/product-view/?no_cache=1&tx_catalogbasic_pi1%5Buid%5D=33), but I don't think it can run the MotoPlus application from the `motoman_driver` package, which would be required to properly simulate a real system. It does run INFORM programs. It also seems to support kinematic simulation of the manipulator.

The [industrial_core](http://wiki.ros.org/industrial_core) metapackage includes a node called the [industrial_robot_simulator](http://wiki.ros.org/industrial_robot_simulator), which implements the same ROS API as all the other ROS-Industrial drivers. It can be used as a drop-in replacement for an actual driver node, but currently only performs simple joint state interpolation (while adhering to velocity & acceleration constraints). Lacking a real simulator it is probably the easiest option though.

Another option (but this would require some work), is to create a version of your urdf that can be simulated using Gazebo. Afaik, only the [SIA10D](http://wiki.ros.org/motoman_sia10d_support) [urdf](https://github.com/ros-industrial/motoman/blob/hydro-devel/motoman_sia10d_support/urdf/sia10d.urdf) contains the necessary tags right now. You would still need to interface it with the appropriate Gazebo controllers though.

---

I might've missed something, so pinging @sedwards.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0